# I am using OOPS concept to make deposit and withdrawl using bank class. But it's showing syntax error

Tags: python, oop

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self,owner,balance):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Bank owner:{self.owner}\n Bank balance:{self.balance}"
    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.amount = amount
        print('Deposit accepted')
        return self.balance += self.amount
    def withrawl (self,amount):
        if self.amount>self.balance:
            print('Withdrawl exceeded the available balance')
        else:
            return self.balance -= self.amount
            print('Withdrawl accepted')
```

Comment: what is the error please ?

Answer (score 1):

In-place operators like `+=` and `-=` cannot be used in a `return` statement.  Modify the value first, then return it.  Also, the last print statement is unreachable.

Some additional info:

We need to unpack what the in-place operation is doing.  Using `x += y` is just syntactic sugar for `x = x + y`.  The `return` keyword stops a function's execution and returns a value or an [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-expression), but it CANNOT return a [statement](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-statement).

From the Python official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-expression

> Assignments are also statements, not expressions.

Putting these pieces together: an in-place assignment, which is a type of assignment, is not an expression, and cannot be returned from a function.

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, owner, balance):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Bank owner:{self.owner}\n Bank balance:{self.balance}"

    def deposit(self, amount):
        print('Deposit accepted')
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def withdrawl(self, amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
            print('Withdrawl exceeded the available balance')
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            print('Withdrawl accepted')
            return self.balance
```

Comment: return allows a function to return a result that can then be stored as a variable, or used in whatever manner a user wants. So how is it that we can't use += and -=?? I am unable to understand this

Comment: I have added more information in my answer.